# Bringing back falied AD DC, what happens to the changes mades on antoher DC?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory

For some reason, our "primary" DC failed and I could not make it back for a little while (let's say 2 weeks). In the meantime, I had to create some GPOs, groups and users on a second, backup DC (same domain).

I can now get my primary DC back, but before I connect it to the network, I wand to be sure that the created items will be replicated on it, not dropped.

Can I plug it back safely ?

Thanks for your answers,

Jérémie

Comment: By "primary" I assume you mean that it held the FSMO roles? Is that correct? If so, did you seize the FSMO roles to the remaining DC while the "primary" DC was down? If so, then DO NOT reconnect the failed "primary" DC. Build a new DC instead. In fact, it's just as easy to build a new DC to replace the failed DC as it is to reconnect the failed DC.

Comment: No seizing, I was just wondering if I had to seize the FSMO ... Seems that not doing anything with it was the right move :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "primary" or "backup" DC - they are multi-master peers. As long as they're part of the same domain and were replicating fine before the failure, they'll continue to replicate again after you return the offline DC to service. You should be fine.

The only exceptions would be if the DC was off for longer than the tombstone lifetime (typically 90-180 days) or if you seized the Operations Master roles on the other DC. In those cases, leave it offline, do a metadata cleanup, and promote a new DC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can then just plug it again, since the FSMOs were not seized ....